# Map Custom Route ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I haven't used .NET Routing before.
I have a URL: **`http://myurl.com/Account/Login/?IsIPA=true`**.
I want to be able to hit this URL with the following: **`http://myurl.com/IPA`**

This is the only custom route I want hit.

Can I create a route just for a single URL like this?

My code that isn't working is:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
    routes.MapRoute("IPA", "Account/Login/{IsIPA}", new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", IsIPA = "true" });
}
```

I get the error:

> The constraint entry `IsIPA` on the route with route template `Account/Login/{IsIPA}=True` must have a string value or be of a type which implements `System.Web.Routing.IRouteConstraint`.

Comment: Try...
routes.MapRoute("IPA", "Account/Login/{IsIPA}", new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", IsIPA = "true" });

Comment: Oh I see what you want. hold on.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Route matching is similar to a switch case statement. The `url` parameter and any default values and constraints are all considered to determine whether or not it is a match with the incoming URL. If the route matches, it will then create a dictionary of route values based on the configuration. If the route does not match, the next route in the collection is tried until a match is found (or not).

This means the order that routes are specified is important. The default route matches *any* URL with 0, 1, 2, or 3 segments. Therefore, in most cases you will need to define your custom route *before* the default route.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "IPA", 
        url: "IPA", 
        defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", IsIPA = "true" });

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

The above configuration will route `http://myurl.com/IPA` to the Controller named `Account` and Action method named `Login`, and pass the additional route key `IsIPA`. This same URL will be built for the Controller/Action/IsIPA combination because it is the first one that matches in the list.

Note that the original URL `http://myurl.com/Account/Login/?IsIPA=true` will still work and still route to the same location. This configuration just adds an extra route to that resource.

Comment: There is a problem with this where using RedirectToAction("Login", "Account") and Url.Action("Login", "Account") both redirect to ~/IPA even when the boolean IsIPA is false. It's solved by calling IsIPA is false explicitly: 
`RedirectToAction("Login", "Account", new { IsIPA = false }) or Url.Action("Login", "Account", new { IsIPA = false })`

Is there a way to make it not route IsIPA = true by default?

Comment: If you set the default value in the route to `false` instead of `true`, the default will be `false`. But if you need to override the default, you either need a different route that matches under different conditions (with a different default value), or you need to explicitly supply the `IsIPA` route value. You could create a custom HTML helper extension to supply the `IsIPA` value, but if you use a single route you must supply it if you want it to be different from the default value.

Comment: I am still having problems with this. E.g. if a user types in the incorrect password and hits Login from the normal /Account/Login (without IPA), the URL will incorrectly redirect to /IPA. If I add a new Route **above** the IPA route like below, when the user is accessing from /IPA and they type an incorrect password, it redirects to /Account/Login, hence losing the IPA branding.
`            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "DefaultLogin",
                url: "Account/Login/",
                defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", IsIPA = UrlParameter.Optional });`

Answer (score 0):

Without testing it, I think that you want this:

```
routes.MapRoute("IPA", "Account/Login/{IsIPA}", 
               new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", IsIPA = "true"});
```

Comment: I got: 404 Error: The resource cannot be found.